# "Sich freuen auf" oder "über"?

Tags: verb, preposition

Wann benutzt man *auf* oder *über* mit *freuen*?

Zum Beispiel:

> Meine Tochter freut sich schon **_** die Sommerferien.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*sich freuen auf* is used when you are looking forward to something, i.e. in an anticipatory context:

> Ich freue mich auf die Sommerferien! / Ich freue mich auf deinen Besuch. (future event)

*sich freuen über* is used when you are excited about something, e.g. a gift or present or a general event.

> Ich freue mich über die Beförderung! / Ich freue mich über deinen Besuch! (present event)

Comment: Could I use über as well with a past event?

Comment: Yes, this is also possible to express your excitement over an event in the past. Depending on context and whether you speak colloquially, you would however change to past tense:
Ich habe mich über deinen Besuch gefreut!

Comment: Oder die andere Variante: Erst hat sie sich nicht auf die Ferien gefreut, weil sie dachte, alle ihre Freunde wären weg.